# Formulas in Powerpoint bar over symbol (\bar) vanishes in presentation mode

Tags: powerpoint, formula

I need to use overlines in formulas.

What is says on the slide (which is what I intend)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vjw.png)

vs. what I get when entering presentation mode
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ig9z.png)

Has anyone seen this before and knows how to resolve the issue?

Copying all slides from the previous presentation into a new file does not resolve the issue.

Working in other presentations, the behaviour is as wished.

Comment: The bars didn't vanish, they just aren't the correct length.  Perhaps you have a font issue?